# Reflection API to choose between instantiation of a base class or its extended version from a different project

Tags: java, oop, reflection

Let's say I have a class named `Human` in `ProjectA`. It is instantiated in the `CreatureBuilder` class of the same project.

Now I want to create a new class called `Cyborg` in a different project, i.e. in `ProjectB`. `ProjectB` has `ProjectA` in its imports, but `ProjectA` knows nothing about `ProjectB`.

`Cyborg extends Human`, and must also be instantiated by `CreatureBuilder` of `ProjectA` (so, `Cyborg` is located in `ProjectB`, I call `CreatureBuilder` from `ProjectB` to instantiate `Cyborg`, but `CreatureBuilder` is located in `ProjectA`, as well as my `Human` class).

I need a logic to create a `Human` when `CreatureBuilder` is instantiated from `ProjectA`, and to create a `Cyborg` when `CreatureBuilder` is instantiated from `ProjectB`.

I know that it can be done by creating an interface with a `getCreature()` method (that will be overridden in `ProjectB`) and a factory class.
But can I use Reflection API instead? From its description, looks like it was designed to do something related (please correct me if I'm wrong). I know that reflections are slow though, and I normally avoid them. But it would be great to see a proof-of-concept, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Seems like you want to [create an extensible application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html). This is done with a [service provider mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Comment: And something else: A cyborg _extends_ a human? Sure?

Comment: Check Lance's answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use generics

```
public class CreatureBuilder<T extends Creature> {
    private Class<T> type;

    public CreatureBuilder<T>(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T build() {
        return type.newInstance();
    }
}

CreatureBuilder<Human> humanBuilder = new CreatureBuilder<>(Human.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `Class.forName()` if you predefine the fully qualified name of a `HumanFactory`.

Let's say that this `HumanFactory` must have this fully qualified name : `com.mycompany.HumanFactory`.

- Project A can try to find such class in its classpath.
- In case it is found, instantiate it and use it to instantiate a Human.
- In case it is not found, instantiate a default Human class.

**In Project A :**

First, declare the interface of a `HumanFactory` :

```
public interface HumanFactoryItf() {
   Human newHuman();
}
```

Then, here is a stub for a `CreatureBuilder` :

```
public class CreatureBuilder {

  public Human build() {
    try {
      HumanFactoryItf factory = 
        (HumanFactoryItf)Class.forName("com.mycompany.HumanFactory").newInstance();
      return factory.newHuman();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
      return new Human();
    }
  }

}
```

**In ProjectB :**

```
package com.mycompany;

public class HumanFactory implements HumanFactoryItf {

  public Human newHuman() {
    return new Cyborg();
  }

}
```

And from the main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  CreatureBuidler cb = ...

  /*
   This line : class.forName("com.mycompany.HumanFactory") 
   will end up instantiating the HumanFactory of ProjectB.
   */
  Human h = cb.build();
}
```

FYI, slf4j uses this pattern in order to decide which logger implementation to use.